# Restore Android studio previous version projects

Tags: android, jdeveloper

If we uninstall android studio to replace it with a new version, do old version projects disappear? I currently have android studio 1.0

Comment: Old Projects history may not be visible, but it will not delete old projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you will not lose your projects since they are not saved in the same place android studio is located

-Dictated through speech to text service on my mobile phone

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "old version projects disappear"? your projects should be in a separate place from your Android Studio installation location.

If you mean that you want to keep the opened and recent projects in Android Studio, then you can just download and open the new version of Android Studio and in the first run it'll ask you to import settings(all settings) from the old version, and if everything imported successfully then delete the old version.

BTW, android studio 1.0 is VERY old, you should keep updating your IDE over time.

Answer (score 0):

No, if you upgrade the Android Studio that will not delete you project work space where you store all projects. It will just install new files of Android Studio and Android Studio 1.0 is very old version, recently Android Studio 3.0.1 is released. you should download that.

Comment: yeah I know but actually I'm taking a course that is using this version so I'm staying on their track .Thank you !